# Как мне посмотреть свой исходный код программы на ассемблере в OllyDbg без лишних нагромождений (без модуля ntdll)?

Tags: ассемблер, ollydbg

Новичок в теме. Ассемблер MASM32. Открываю свой ассемблерный код программы в OllyDbg  - а там "много букв"...Какой-то модуль ntdll отобразился. Мне бы свой код только увидеть.

[image: Изображение 2 - Открыл в OllyDbg]

[image: Изображение 1 - Исходный код на ассемблере.]

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался! Нужно было в меню Viev выбрать соответствующую опцию(Executable modules).
[image: Скрин меню OllyDbg]

Answer (score 1):

Нужно просто один раз нажать F9 или кнопку выполнения на панели инструментов, после этого исполнение остановится на точке входа вашей программы.